Get products with Qonversion - React-native
I'm using react-native and trying to get products in Qonversion but I can't.
I used:
const products = await Qonversion.getSharedInstance().products();

The command return a product, but I'm not working with the response. This is an object but I cannot check the proprieties.
In DOCS, the suggestion is to use:
const products: Map<string, Product> = await Qonversion.getSharedInstance().products();

But the command not working.
Can someone help me?
